# save array in session variable

Tags: php, session

In php4 the following syntax is used to save values in sessions:

```
<?php
    $userSession[auth] = "ok";
    $userSession[loginid] = $loginId;
    $userSession[firstName] = $firstName;
    $userSession[lastName] = $lastName;          
    session_register("userSession");
?>
```

I would like to know what is the best practices for using sessions in php5.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: As noted in a few answers below, you must call `session_start()` first.  The reason being that `session_register()` implictly calls `session_start()`.  Since you are removing that function (which is now removed from PHP >= 5.4), you need to explicitly call `session_start()` before you can work with `$_SESSION`

Comment: Seems odd to flag this as off-topic. Looks like the user is trying to upgrade a php4 or early php 5 app to be more php 5 compliant and wants to know the best practices for using sessions now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than loading an array into the session in this manner, you may want to just consider adding those elements to the session itself:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['auth'] = "ok";
$_SESSION['loginid'] = $loginId;
$_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
$_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
$_SESSION['userSession'] = $userSession;
```

As @Fallen commented, don't forget to do a `session_start()` first.

As a side note, you should quote the strings used as keys in your array:

```
$userSession["auth"] = "ok";
```

Comment: to OP: don't forget to start session :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `session_register`!  You can just read/write from `$_SESSION`.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['userSession'] = array(
    "auth" => "ok",
    "loginid" => $loginId,
    "firstName" => $firstName,
    "lastName" => $lastName
);
```